# Javascript regex replace (encoded) url

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to alter a server response that contains a url for social login.
The url looks like this (I wrapped to multiple line for better readability):

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=clientid&scope=public_profile,email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=
https%3A%2F%2Fsomeotherurl%3A5000%2Fsignin-facebook
&state=reallylongstring
```

The part I want to change is on the second line, but in a way that the `signin-facebook` part is kept, like so:

`https://newurl.com/signin-facebook`
(signin-facebook could be something else like `signin-linkedin`, etc...)

So the complete replaced url would be:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=clientid&scope=public_profile,email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=
https://newurl.com/signin-facebook
&state=reallylongstring
```

This is as far as I have gotten, this replaces the correct segment, but is leaving the `signin-facebook` part off:

`/^https:\/\/(.*&redirect_uri=)([^&]*)(.*)/`

Playground link:
https://regexr.com/4j5h6

The url segment to be replaced will be already url encoded by the time the regex engine hits it, so I guess somehow I have to match for a string that is between an encoded `/` and the `&state=...` part, but I'm stuck with it for now.

Comment: No, it is not multiline. I just wrapped it so it doesn't get too wide on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups including the http part in the first group:

```
^(https:\/\/.*&redirect_uri=)[^&]*(signin-[^&]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `https:\/\/.*&redirect_uri=` Match from http till &redirect_uri=
- `)`  Close group
- `[^&]*` Match 0+ times not an ampersand
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `signin-[^&]+` Match signin- followed by 1+ not an ampersans
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g3xOjX/1)

In the replacement refer to the 2 capturing groups.

```
$1https://newurl.com/$2
```

```js
const regex = /^(https:\/\/.*&redirect_uri=)[^&]*(signin-[^&]+)/g;
const str = `https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=clientid&scope=public_profile,email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=
https%3A%2F%2Fsomeotherurl%3A5000%2Fsignin-facebook&state=reallylongstring`;
const subst = `$1https://newurl.com/$2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I guess somehow I have to match for a string that is between an encoded `/` and the `&state=..`

Since encoded `/` is `%2F`, you may use this regex:

```
/^(https:\/\/.*&redirect_uri=).*%2F([^&]+)(&state=.*)/i
```

And replace it by:

```
$1https://newurl.com/$2$3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Of0wfU/1)

Comment: Different approaches. My regex assumes there is an encoded `%2F` and the other one assumes there is always a string with `signin-` in the `redirect_uri` query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL API to do this.

> Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=url

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=clientid&scope=public_profile,email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsomeotherurl%3A5000%2Fsignin-facebook&state=reallylongstring');

url.searchParams.set('redirect_uri', 'https://new.url/xyz');

const newUrl = url.toString();

//output
console.log(newUrl);
```

```css
/* ignore this - just a style hack for stackoverflow */
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
}
.as-console-row-code {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line !important;
  color: green;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the URL api is not available to me. The regex is executed in an IIS server, not in the browser. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my post.